# Kotlin|Tornadofx: How to open new fxml screen on mouse click in another fxml screen

Tags: kotlin, fxml, tornadofx

I have a very simple task but can't do it.

I have Kotlin|Tornadofx app.

I open the fxml screen:

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root : VBox by fxml("/Screen 1.fxml")
}
```

There is a button in Screen1.fxml. I need the app to open another screen (Screen2.fxml) on button pressed in Screen1.fxml.

I got stuck by this. Only a function call is available from Screen1.fxml by means of onAction="#FunctiondefinedinMainView". But swapping views in MainView is only available by

```
button("Go to Screen2") {
action {
replaceWith<Screen2>()
}
```

constructs, which I cannot accomplish because I only can call a function from within Screen1.fxml. And I do not have buttons in MainView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add an id to your button in your `Screen 1.fxml` file:

```
<Button fx:id="myButtonId">
```

Then, you can get a reference to that button in your `MainView`:

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root: VBox by fxml("/Screen 1.fxml")
    val button: Button by fxid("myButtonId")
}
```

Now, you can set the click listener for your button to replace the screen:

```
class MainView : View() {
    override val root: VBox by fxml("/Screen 1.fxml")
    val button: Button by fxid("myButtonId")
    init {
        button.setOnAction {
            replaceWith<Screen2>()
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this before but it should work, in case it doesn't, feel free to leave a comment.